# bitcoin transaction showing unconfirmed over 6 days

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

A friend sent some bitcoin to me worth $91 on May 7 2017 (with extremely low fees without initially telling me). It show unconfirmed till 10 may 17 when it returned to sender and was able to login and send bitcoin to other users.  Surprisingly, I login this morning and the bitcoin has resent itself to my wallet.  Since then I have tried two transfer with extremely high fees.  It is showing pending and I need those transfer to really go through. Pls how do i solve this problem. The hashcode is b27e371f54cd24d2bdcc8d9e283dc7929589949c6d8ab47232feb6d13cb9f778.
Please I need urgent help.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only thing we can do is to wait for the transaction confirmation, like me now. This link show that more than 120.000 transaction unconfirmed including ours https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions

Hope that we get confirmed before it resent